# How can I read a Blob object in Javascript as JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/json'});
```

`response.data` contains JSON file, I want to read the contents of this file and assign them as a JSON string to a variable in javascript.

I've tried a few things with `FileReader.readAsText(file)` but I'm not able to properly convert it into a simple JSON string.

P.S.: The `response.data` is an arraybuffer, so if there's a direct conversion that's possible without creating a Blob object, that should also solve the problem.

Comment: try to create a new text file and add data

Comment: Use `await file.text()` or `file.text().then(jsonString => ...)`

Comment: It appears that you are trying to process a fetch response.  And if is a json file then why not use [Response.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)?  Or if you really want an array then use [Response.arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/json'});

file.text()
        .then(value => {
           self.objectName = JSON.parse(value);
           console.log(self.objectName);
         })
         .catch(error => {
           console.log("Something went wrong" + error);
         });
```

Did the trick for me.